# Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 not installing on Windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-2015, windows-10

I am running Windows 10 Enterprise and i had Visual Studio Enterprise 2015 installed and it was up and running until i the time i used an application called **Duplicate File Remover** to free up space occupied by duplicate files on my HDD. After the operation,visual studio could not run so i opted to uninstall it and reinstall. While installing i received be error below:

[image]

could anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: Did you run the setup 'As Administrator'?

Comment: yes i tried that and even removed all visual studio residual files after uninstalling

Comment: You might want to check if your Windows 10 version is the latest, as well as the VS version you're trying to install. I have seen this problem in the past, and I tend to think the issue (and implicitly the fix) is/was on their end.

Comment: I assume you checked the installation log file? What does it say is the issue?

Comment: maybe try refreshing your OS first...this **Duplicate File Remover** may have removed some system files/components _(if the operation was performed on the system drive as well)_ needed by VS2015 for the installation process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running Windows Update which will installing/fix any missing files

[VS2015 Prerequisites failed to install](https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/322203/vs2015-prerequisites-failed-to-install.html)

Comment: let me find it ill send it to you

Comment: thanx it fixed the problem

Comment: Glad it helped, please can you accept my answer to help other people see this has helped. - http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers